# Validate field in Marshmallow but don't deserialize it

Tags: python, json, validation, marshmallow

I'm trying to build a Marshmallow schema based on a model, but with one additional field. While this seemed to work by declaring the special field by itself and then setting `meta.model` to my assigned model, I fail to find a solution so that the additional field gets validated (it is marked as required), but does not turn up in the resulting, deserialized object.

I tried setting it as `excluded` and `dump_only`, but to no avail, either the validation does not take place, or the deserialized object also contains the additional field (which then clashes with my ORM).

Answer (score 1):

For now I solved it by subclassing my model schema, adding the additional field there, and then - before loading my data through the model schema - validating it through the subclassed schema.

If there is a more elegant solution I'd still love to hear it.